# JMeter: Get Post Request URL and Data

Tags: java, performance, jmeter

I"M practicing JMeter performance testing using this [website](https://www.phptravels.net/). There is username, password field and login button.

How to know the username URL, password URL and login action URL which need to supply to POST method in JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the request curl using any proxy tool or simply using "inspect" feature on your browser.
From the curl, you can easily generate the jmeter script you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use your browser's "inspect element" feature.

**Request URL** - https://www.phptravels.net/demo/account/login

**Request Method** - POST

**Form Data**

username - username

password - password

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the parameter for username and password?

Comment: They are as indicated above. Username for username and password for password

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of building a [web test plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html) is just [recording](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. From JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create"

   [image]
2. Open HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and click "Start"

   [image]
3. Locate `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation and [add it to your browser](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-add-a-trusted-certificate-authority-certificate-to-chrome-and-firefox/).
4. Amend your [browser proxy configuration](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-set-proxy-server-all-major-internet-browsers-windows) to look like

   [image]
5. Execute your test steps in browser
6. JMeter should capture the requests and generate the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers under the [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)

The alternative way of recording a JMeter test is using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/), in this case you will not have to worry about proxies and certificates.